# Backbone js subRouter

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

How can I create a subrouter for my backbone application?
I have found some code, but can't get it work( https://gist.github.com/1235317 ). Route handler is not executed after router creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that to the constructor function in the end

```
// grab the full URL
var hash = Backbone.history.getHash();

// check if there is already a part of the URL that this subview cares about...
var hashPart = hash.substr(prefix.length + 1, hash.length);

// ...if so, trigger the subroute immediately.  this supports the case where 
// a user directly navigates to a URL with a subroute on the first page load.
if (hashPart && hashPart != "") {
    Backbone.history.loadUrl(prefix + hashPart);
}
```